# Alternative of cookies.onChanged in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I have an chrome extension and I am porting to Microsoft Edge now. I am using cookies.onChanged.addListener method in chrome. As Microsoft Edge does not support cookies.onChanged API what can be used as an alternative so that I can listen on any cookie change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using a content script and check page cookies periodically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @wOxxOm.